# Guess the number, play again

Tags: python

I'm making a guess the number game. My code is almost complete but I need to make it so that the program asks the player if they want to play again and then restarts. Could someone help me with how I should go about that? I tried making a new function ex. def game_play_again and then call the game_play() function but it's not reseting the attempts which leads to it not looping correctly.

This is my code right now

```
import random
MIN = 1
MAX = 100
attempts = 5
win = False


number = random.randint(MIN,MAX)
last_hint = f"{'EVEN' if number%2 == 0 else 'ODD'}"

#print game instructions
def game_start():
    print(f"Im thinking of a number between {MIN} and {MAX}. Can you guess it within 
{attempts} attempts? ")
    input("Press enter to start the game ")


  #process user input
def game_play():
    global number, attempts, last_hint, win
    while attempts > 0:
    print()
    print(f"You have {attempts} {'attempts' if attempts > 1 else 'attempt'} left.")

if attempts == 1:
  print(f"This is your last chance. So i'll give you one more hint. Its's an {last_hint} number.")


while True:
  try: 
    guess = int(input("Try a lucky number: "))
    if guess in range(MIN, MAX+1):
       break
    else: 
      print(f"Please enter numbers between {MIN} and {MAX} only!")
  except ValueError:
      print("Plese enter numbers only!")


if guess == number:
   win = True
   break


if attempts == 1:
  break

if guess > number:
  if guess-number > 5:
    print("Your guess is too high. Try something lower.")
  else:
    print("Come on you are very close. Just a bit lower.")
else:
  if number-guess > 5:
    print("Your guess is too low. Try something higher.")
  else:
    print("Come on you are very close. Just a bit higher.")
attempts -= 1

    
#print game results
def game_finish(win):
    if win:
       print("Congratulations you guessed it!")
    else: 
       print(f"The number I was thinking of is {number}. Sorry you lost. Better luck next time!")
  





game_start()
game_play()
game_finish(win)
```

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code.

Comment: Your design is kind of inside out. You want to create functions which _do_ things, and have the calling code interface between them and the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reset your variables to initial values and then call game_play()

```
def game_finish(win):
    if win:
       print("Congratulations you guessed it!")
    else: 
       print(f"The number I was thinking of is {number}. Sorry you lost. Better luck next time!")
    
    want_play_again = int(input("Want play again? [1-Yes / 2-No]"))
    if want_play_again == 1:
        game_play_again()
    else:
        print("Bye")
```

/

```
def game_play_again():
    attempts = 0
    win = False
    game_play()
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a `while(True)` loop, write a menu driven statement asking the user if they want to repeat. If they do, initialise values and call game methods. If they do not, break the loop.

pseudocode:

```
while(True):
     choice = input('play again? y/n)
     if choice=='y':
           attempts, win = 5, False
           number = random.randint(MIN,MAX)
           last_hint = f"{'EVEN' if number%2 == 0 else 'ODD'}"
           game_start()
           game_play()
           game_finish()
     elif choice=='n':
           break
     else:
           print('invalid input')
```

The above code should be in `main`, with all methods within its scope.

Better yet, in place of all the initializations, add an `init()` method declaring them and call them when necessary.

The indentation in the code you have submitted is faulty, so I'm not sure if a related error is involved.